# Typescript make param optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwBYwLwwDwBUB8AKASzAKgIEMAbAETKjIH4AuGLASmYG8YATWs5rDAA%20MAK5huCAGZEE3AL5ocMDgChVMTTAJSYhYqUo06rFRq0WATgiijLYFTz7MiJctT4x55zd58xrW3szCwteOmZxSRkwOX9vPygATwAHBBgAJQQILFT09DULJAQKChBmaEsiAHNVP1BIWGsIAEZmLJy8tHhkDA7ctPwuYtLymAByEbLx%20VYAOnCyOamQVQboAOyAJkiJaVlubsQkPHnF9VUgA)

I am trying to make a parameter optional, but still make typescript understand what will get returned from function.

If param is defined, then type of param is returned. Otherwise - if no param is provided, function will return undefined.

```
const meh = <T>(initialData?: T): { data: T | undefined} => {
    if (initialData) {
        return { data: initialData }
    }

    return {
        data: undefined
    }
}

const res1: undefined = meh().data // is ok:

type ResType = {
    hello: string
}

const res2: ResType = meh<ResType>({ hello: 'hello'}).data.hello // TS error: Object is possibly undefined
```

Which makes sense. Though, I found [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) and I though I could do something like

`const meh = <T>(initialData?: T): { data: T ? T : undefined} => {`

, but it gives syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use function overloads?

```
function meh(): { data: undefined };
function meh<T>(initialData: T): { data: T };

function meh<T>(initialData?: T): any {
    if (initialData) {
        return { data: initialData }
    }

    return {
        data: undefined
    }
}

type ResType = {
    hello: string
}

const res1: ResType = meh<ResType>({ hello: 'hello'}).data
const res2: undefined = meh().data
```

Comment: I never used them before. Thank you so much!